# Bootstrap 5 - How to overide default colours

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap 5 (5.2.1) with a form.

I'm trying to override the default form validation styles. In particular, the coloured 'tick' (or 'check') icon that appears when a form field is correctly completed/validated.

The Developer Tools panel shows the relevant code which controls the presentation of the validated form (see below). But, this is generated by a **_forms.scss** file, which doesn't seem to exist in the files/folders downloaded from Bootstrap.

Anyhow, I haven't ever used .scss

Wondering if there is any easy way to change default colours in Bootstrap 5 (including the SVG icon referenced in the CSS below) - without using SCSS?

```
.form-control.is-valid, .was-validated .form-control:valid {
    border-color: #198754;
    padding-right: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem);
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' 
    viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath fill='%23198754' d='M2.3 6.73.6 4.53c-.4-1.04.46-1.4 
    1.1-.8l1.1 1.4 3.4-3.8c.6-.63 1.6-.27 1.2.7l-4 4.6c-.43.5-.8.4-1.1.1z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right calc(0.375em + 0.1875rem) center;
    background-size: calc(0.75em + 0.375rem) calc(0.75em + 0.375rem);
}
```

P.S.

I added the above code to my custom.css file, with changed colours, but this didn't work.

Comment: Try adding ```!important``` at the end of all your ```css``` declarations.

Comment: @Innovin Thanks for reply. I should have added that I did use !important but this didn't work.

Comment: What is the file order in your html file? ```custom.css``` should come after ```bootstrap.css```

Comment: @Innovin My custom.css file comes after bootstrap.min.css

Comment: I notice that the border colour does change but can't change the SVG tick/check icon.

Comment: I have posted an answer. Do check if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).
How to go about this would be this way:

First off all, assign an id to your body tag eg `<body id='override'>`

Now in your `custom.css`, just change it to this:

```
#override .form-control.is-valid, #override .was-validated .form-control:valid {
    border-color: #198754;
    padding-right: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem);
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' 
    viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath fill='%23198754' d='M2.3 6.73.6 4.53c-.4-1.04.46-1.4 
    1.1-.8l1.1 1.4 3.4-3.8c.6-.63 1.6-.27 1.2.7l-4 4.6c-.43.5-.8.4-1.1.1z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right calc(0.375em + 0.1875rem) center;
    background-size: calc(0.75em + 0.375rem) calc(0.75em + 0.375rem);
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Decoding the URL:

```
#override .form-control.is-valid, #override .was-validated .form-control:valid {
    border-color: #198754;
    padding-right: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem);
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' 
    viewBox='0 0 8 8'><path fill='#198754' d='M2.3 6.73.6 4.53c-.4-1.04.46-1.4 
    1.1-.8l1.1 1.4 3.4-3.8c.6-.63 1.6-.27 1.2.7l-4 4.6c-.43.5-.8.4-1.1.1z'/></svg>);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right calc(0.375em + 0.1875rem) center;
    background-size: calc(0.75em + 0.375rem) calc(0.75em + 0.375rem);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! EXCEPT that the SVG tick/check icon colour doesn't change. I notice its fill colour is set as **fill='%23198754'** How to change that? Setting the colour as a hex colour (e.g. fill='#0000ff') doesn't work, even with !important.

Comment: It's ```HTML encoding```. Change ```%23198754``` to ```#198754```

Comment: It seems most of your text in ```background-image``` declaration is html encoded. I will update my answer with a decoded version.

Comment: Thanks again for help. I have used your decoded HTML/CSS with updated background-image code (I set fill to fill='#0000ff' and border-color to border-color: #0000ff;). The border color now works (displays as blue) but SVG icon does not change (stays green). !important used.

Comment: It is **URL encoded** because it is a URL being passed to `url()`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by URL encoded (??) The background-image declaration uses a URL constructor but, if I understand correctly, that just dumps a hard-coded SVG <path> into the form field background. Or am I totally wrong?

Comment: @Mekong ```Url encoding``` converts characters into a format that can be transmitted over the Internet. So stuff like ```<``` and ```>``` get replaced with ```%3c``` and ```%3e``` etcetera. Rather than using the ```url``` constructor, just pass in the full URL.

Comment: @Innovin Thanks. I've since done some reading online and now have an overview of URL encoding. Wasn't a concept I'd ever come across before.

Comment: @Mekong Glad I could help :) .Yep, ```url encoding``` can be very useful, but never in the case of ```CSS``` declarations.